# Display Algolia results on product view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller, algolia

I'm new on Ror,
I would like to display on my products.search page all my products cards avalaible, and add an algolia searchbar filtering and displaying results cards instead of all the products on this page.
I know it's not that hard but I don't succeed to make it works.
My algolia index works correctly since I get all my products on Algolia website.
Actually I don't find the good method to put in my controller and the good code to put in my view...:-(

Thk you for your help. 
Here is my code:

app.js:

```
//= require algolia/v3/algoliasearch.min
```

ProductsController.rb:

```
  def search
    @products = Product.where(active: true)
???????
  end
```

Product.rb:

```
include AlgoliaSearch
algoliasearch if: :active? do
  attribute :name, :brand, :category, :color, :size, :price
end
```

products/search.html.erb:

```
<!-- Algolia searchbar -->
<!-- HTML Markup -->
<div class="aa-input-container" id="aa-input-container">
    <input type="search" id="aa-search-input" class="aa-input-search" placeholder="Trouver un article..." name="search" autocomplete="off" />
    <svg class="aa-input-icon" viewBox="XXXXXXXX">
        <path d="XXXXXXXXXX" />
    </svg>
</div>
<!-- Include AlgoliaSearch JS Client and autocomplete.js library -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/algoliasearch/3/algoliasearch.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/autocomplete.js/0/autocomplete.min.js"></script>
<!-- Initialize autocomplete menu -->
<script>
var client = algoliasearch('XXXXX', 'XXXXXXXXXX');
var index = client.initIndex('Product');
//initialize autocomplete on search input (ID selector must match)
autocomplete('#aa-search-input',
{ hint: false }, {
    source: autocomplete.sources.hits(index, {hitsPerPage: 5}),
    //value to be displayed in input control after user's suggestion selection
    displayKey: 'name',
    //hash of templates used when rendering dataset
    templates: {
        //'suggestion' templating function used to render a single suggestion
        suggestion: function(suggestion) {
          return '<span>' +
            suggestion._highlightResult.name.value + '</span><span>' +
            suggestion._highlightResult.category.value + '</span>';
        }
    }
});
</script>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9">
    <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <% if product.active? %>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading preview">

        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <strong><%= link_to product.name, product %></strong>

          <strong><%= product.price %> euros</strong>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To display Algolia on your current view you can just rely on Front-end search, therefore you can remove the `@products = Product.where(active: true)` line in your controller and the loop in your view.

That said, your code seems correct. Do you have any records in your Algolia index? If not, you can force the reindexing by using `Product.reindex!`.

Comment: Thk you Gianluca! But still not working..:-(  I removed my method from the controller and the loop in the view... I have 20 records in my Algolia index. And did the reindex!  Then I tried in my controller:   'def search
    (at)results = Product.search('', hitsPerPage: 10)
  end' and in my view '<%= will_paginate @results %>'  But still not working... :-(